# replace text in html with sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Could you please advice how to replace text in the html tags?

```html
<link href="*" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

I want to get instead of example above:

```html
<link href="${favicon}" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

`${favicon}` = favicon.png - just for example

IMPORTANT! Use only `awk` or `sed` because I will do it in the shell

I tried to use

```bash
sed "s/<link href=\"*\" rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" />/<link href=\"${favicon}\" rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" />" index.html
```

But it didn't work
`sed: 1: "s/<link href="*" rel="i ...": bad flag in substitute command: '>'`

Comment: When HTML and awk/sed appear in the same sentence, there is usually something wrong. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @Cyrus Yeah, you are right, but I just need to replace one word and use parser for it overhead...

Comment: If you use `/` to delimit `s///`, you have to escape all occurrences of it in the regex or replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that

```
<link href="*" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

does contain `*` character which has special meaning in regular expression (zero-or-more repeats), therefore I suggest using [`index`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function for compensating that, let `file.html` content be

```
<html>
  <body>
    <link href="*" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  </body>
</html>
```

then

```
awk -v old='<link href="*" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />' -v rep='<link href="${favicon}" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />' '{start=index($0,old);end=start+length(old)}start{$0=substr($0,1,start-1) rep substr($0,end)}{print}' file.html
```

gives output

```
<html>
  <body>
    <link href="${favicon}" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Explanation: I use `-v` flags to ram string to replace (into variable `old`) and replacement string (into variable `rep`), then for each line I compute where is `start` and `end` of old string, if it is not there start value is 0, otherwise positive integer, if latter is case I use `substr` function twice to get part before old and after old and concatenate them using replacement string and use that as whole line (`$0`), each line is `print`ed.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

using sed extended regex and two capture groups and useing # as sed script separator ...

```
$ sed -E "s#(<link href=\")\*(\" rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" />)#\1${favicon}\2>#" index.html
<link href="favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />>
```

but this might need change if more than one match in file and only want to change one or if there are other characters on same line